When does hardhat-deploy skip a function on the deploy script
When running this script for the second time, the hardhat-deploy library detects that it had already deployed the pool artifact so it skipped that part. It did not skip the pool initialisation. So when running the initialisation, it fails.
Shouldn't it skip the whole deploy function? If not, what is a good way/practice to make it skip the function?
const func: DeployFunction = async function ({
  getNamedAccounts,
  deployments,
  ...hre
}: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  const { deploy } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const poolConfig = await loadPoolConfig(MARKET_NAME as ConfigNames);
  const network = (
    process.env.FORK ? process.env.FORK : hre.network.name
  ) as eNetwork;

  const { address: addressesProviderAddress } = await deployments.get(
    POOL_ADDRESSES_PROVIDER_ID
  );
  const commonLibraries = await getPoolLibraries();

  // Deploy common Pool contract
  const poolArtifact = await deploy(POOL_IMPL_ID, {
    contract: "Pool",
    from: deployer,
    args: [addressesProviderAddress],
    libraries: {
      ...commonLibraries,
    },
    ...COMMON_DEPLOY_PARAMS,
  });

  // Initialize implementation
  const pool = await getPool(poolArtifact.address);
  await waitForTx(await pool.initialize(addressesProviderAddress));
  console.log("Initialized Pool Implementation");
};

func.id = "PoolImplementation";
func.tags = ["market"];

export default func;

